# How can I call an embeded swfs function from within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf that is a preloader for another swf (a game). I need to callback to the game swf from Javascript but can't figure out how to do this. I can call back into the preloader by registering a callback using the ExternalInterface.

I tried `document.getElementById("preloader")` which returns an object. The `preloader` has a public property called `GameObj` which returns a reference to the game object which has been loaded by the preloader.

The issue is, `document.getElementById("preloader").GameObj` is always `null`.

Is it possible to do this or do I need a wrapper call within the preloader?

Comment: you can't access from javascript anything from inside a swf, you can make calls and receive calls and that's it. SO callback into the preloader like you do and let the preloader communicate with the loaded swf.

Comment: I had a feeling that was going to be the answer. Thanks BotMaster

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), but is there some reason you can't put your preloader in the same swf?